# Maximum likelihood estimation using a random number generator

Tags: maximum-likelihood, random-generation, numerical-integration

Imagine that I have a random number generator $X$ where it is impossible (or mathematicaly intractable) to calculate its probability density function
- this can happen when we compose several simpler random variables, that is, the parameters of a random variable are determined by another random variables.

That random variable depends of one (or more) parameters $\alpha$ that I want to ajust in order to maximize a likelihood function $L$ (for a given a set of observations $x_1, ..., x_n$)

My question is how can I find the parameters $\alpha$ that maximize the likelihood function using just the random number generator.

Comment: Do you mean to say that $X$ is just a function of some other (presumably finite) collection of random variables? And $α$ is the parameter vector for all these subordinate random variables?

Comment: @Kodiologist, ignore that, it was just an exemple, I'm looking for an answer for the general case where we don't have the analytical expression of the probability density function, just a random number generator.

Comment: A random number generator is an ordinary concept, not a well-defined mathematical object. If you're trying to ask a math problem, you need to describe it in more detail. If, on the other hand, you have a specific real-world problem you're trying to solve, specify that. [See here.](http://arfer.net/w/statqgl)

Comment: @Kodiologist, One exemple: the composition of a random variable generated by a poisson distribution ($X\sim Poi(\lambda)$) with another generated by a log normal distribution. That is, for each trial $\lambda \sim ln N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Comment: That's just a hierarchical model. One example of methods available to find MLEs of a hierarchical model is Markov chain Monte Carlo. (That particular example might have a nicer solution; I haven't checked.)

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: @Kodiologist, Maybe, I need to study about that topic. Thank you!